# Why all differentials going out of row 1 and 2 of the $E_3$ page are zeros?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, spectral-sequences

Here is the paper I am reading "Guide to the Serre Spectral Sequence in 10 easy steps!"(it is found free online but I do not know how to attach it):

The paper said that "going out of row 1 and 2 of the $E_3$ page all the differentials are zeros" but I am not sure why this is correct, what should be the length of the differential arrow in the $E_3$ page, could someone explain this to me please?

Comment: It might be helpful to provide a link to the paper, or even to provide details here summarizing what's going on.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/tanj/notes/sssguide.pdf here is the link

Comment: why downvoting my question also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about the sentence on p. 2.

On p. 1 of the document, the author says, $d_r: E_r^{s,t} \to E_r^{s+r,t-r+1}$. That is, $d_r$ goes to the right by $r$, down by $r-1$. At $E_3$, for example, the differentials go down by 2, and since there is nothing below row 0, there are no possible nonzero differential starting in rows 0 and 1. This is indicated in the picture. The text also says that the differentials starting in row 2 must be zero, but this is wrong and it is also contradicted by their own picture. Indeed, the picture on p. 8 (and the ensuing computation) shows a nonzero $d_3$ starting in row 2. Including row 2 in the sentence on p. 2 is a mistake.

Comment: Why the downvote?